# Fetching data from a CSV file

Tags: parsing, vba, excel

One of my professional software I use everyday provides analysis results in *.csv format from which I need to extract data. I have written a script that first converts from text to columns, and then takes out the data I need rearranging it the way I want. My problem is that it is not very fast while I will need to use it a lot. I am pretty sure it can be made more efficient with proper iterators but everything else I have tried I hit the wall somewhere along the way.

Now to the specifics. Here is how the Excel data looks like after I transform from text to column and delete some columns I know do not contain any interesting data.

Two columns are remaining:

```
xxx  
xxx  
xxx  
.  
.  
KnownText1 KnownText2  
Data1.1 Data1.2  
Data1.3 Data1.4  
.  
.  
Data1.m Data1.n  
xxx  
xxx  
xxx  
.  
Knowntext1 Knowntext2
Data2.1 Data2.2  
Data2.3 Data2.4  
.  
.  
Data2.k Data2.l
xxx
xxx
```

The `xxx` can be anything. `Knowntext1` is always the same and shows the start of a new data block that needs to be captured. Number of blocks can vary as well as the number of rows within each block.

I want my data to become:

```
Knowntext1 Knowntext2 Knowntext1 Knowntext2 ...  
Data1.1 Data1.2 Data2.1 Data2.2 ...  
Data1.3 Data1.4 Data2.3 Data2.4 ...  
...  
Data1.m Data1.n Data2.k Data2.l ...
```

Here is my VBA code. Any ideas on how to make an efficient iterator to do the same?

```vb
Sub CopyFromCSV()

Dim RngData As Range
Dim RngCopy As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim nTrims As Integer
Dim nDrafts As Integer
Dim maxDrafts As Integer


' Transform text to columns by "," seperator
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

' Removes the " " thousand seperator from the displacement column
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

' Delete columns other than those containing information of Displacement and MaxVCG
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C:Z").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

' Find the actual used range which we want to loop through
Set RngData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

' Initialise variables for number of trim groups and the maximum number of drafts in all trim groups
nTrims = 0
maxDrafts = 0

With RngData
    'Loop through all cells in first column
    For Each rCell In .Columns(1).Cells
        ' If Value is "Intact Displ(MT)", a new trim group is detected
        If rCell.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Intact Displ(MT)" Then
            nTrims = nTrims + 1 'Number of trims groups incremented
            nDrafts = 1 'Number of drafts in this trim group initialised to 1
            Set RngCopy = rCell.Resize(1, 2) 'Initiate the range that will include data for this trim group

        ' If Value is numeric, it means the row contains data for the initiated trim group
        ElseIf IsNumeric(rCell.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then
            nDrafts = nDrafts + 1 'Number of drafts in the trim group incremented
            Set RngCopy = RngCopy.Resize(nDrafts, 2) 'Range to be copied is updated
            If nDrafts > maxDrafts Then
            'In case not all trim groups have the same amount of drafts, we need to set maxDrafts to know the size of the final selection
                maxDrafts = nDrafts
            End If

        ' If another type of data is detected, the range to be copied is frozen and copied at the top of the sheet, after the last column
        ' Test on nTrims > 0 necessary to avoid the action to occur before any valuable data is detected
        ElseIf Not (IsNumeric(rCell.Cells(1, 1).Value)) And nTrims > 0 Then
            RngCopy.Copy
            Cells(1, 2 * nTrims + 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        End If
    Next rCell
End With

' Relevant data was copied after last column
' First two columns of original data can be deleted
Columns("A:B").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

' Numeric data of the transformed table is selected and sent to clipboard ready to paste in global spreadsheet
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(maxDrafts, 2 * nTrims)).Select
Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main slow-down there is that you are copying and recopying the interesting data on every `xxxx` line. That's fairly easy to fix.

Your `With RngCopy` construct didn't appear to be doing anything, so I removed it. In any case it is not a great idea to have a 'With` block that reallocates the referenced object internally.

You would do well to use "Select" a lot less often, and there is no need to continuously redefine RngCopy. Here is an update that should run quicker and look calmer:

```
Sub CopyFromCSV()

Dim RngData As Range
Dim RngCopy As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim nTrims As Integer
Dim nDrafts As Integer
Dim maxDrafts As Integer


' Transform text to columns by "," seperator
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

' Removes the " " thousand seperator from the displacement column
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

' Delete columns other than those containing information of Displacement and MaxVCG
Columns("B:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("C:Z").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

' Initialise variables for number of trim groups and the maximum number of drafts in all trim groups
nTrims = 0
nDrafts = 0 ' nDrafts > 0 will mean we are in a data group
maxDrafts = 0

'Loop through all cells in first column
For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
    ' First check for data group to copy
    ' If non-numeric data is detected, any range to be copied is copied to the top of the sheet, after the last column
    ' Test on nDrafts > 0 to only paste valuable data, and only once
    If Not (IsNumeric(rCell.Cells(1, 1).Value)) And nDrafts > 0 Then
        RngCopy.Resize(nDrafts, 2).Copy Destination:=Cells(1, 2 * nTrims + 1)

        If nDrafts > maxDrafts Then maxDrafts = nDrafts
        nDrafts = 0 ' we have copied this data, don't copy again

    End If
    ' If Value is "Intact Displ(MT)", a new trim group is detected
    If rCell.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Intact Displ(MT)" Then
        nTrims = nTrims + 1 'Number of trims groups incremented
        nDrafts = 1 'Number of drafts in this trim group initialised to 1
        Set RngCopy = rCell 'Initiate the range that will include data for this trim group

    ' If Value is numeric, it means the row contains data for the initiated trim group
    ElseIf IsNumeric(rCell.Cells(1, 1).Value) And nDrafts > 0 Then
        nDrafts = nDrafts + 1 'Number of drafts in the trim group incremented
    End If    
Next rCell
' Copy any remaining data group
If nDrafts > 0 Then
    RngCopy.Resize(nDrafts, 2).Copy Destination:=Cells(1, 2 * nTrims + 1)
    If nDrafts > maxDrafts Then maxDrafts = nDrafts
End If

' Relevant data was copied after last column
' First two columns of original data can be deleted
Columns("A:B").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

' Numeric data of the transformed table is selected and sent to clipboard ready to paste in global spreadsheet
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(maxDrafts, 2 * nTrims)).Select
Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: One thing I can't quite work out is how you are replacing out the spaces in column A and then testing for a text phrase that has a space in it. Maybe this works for your data, but I had to work around it.